# upperlower case just in tags (strtolower )

Tags: php, var

I am finishing up a system in PHP, where I generate some custom tags where later, use str_replace to replace certain values​​.

The question is, I spend such information as follows:

```
$tag = array("<#id>" => $id,"<#link>" => $link,"<#link>");
$output = str_replace(array_keys($tag),array_values($tag),$output);
```

Since, the variable $output, I have something like:

```
$output = "This canT bE UpPeR LoWeD <#LINK> <#id>";
```

So my problem appears, I can not use strtolower because I can not leave all the variable in lower case.

I need a way in which I can leave in lowercase, only tags!

Any Friend of battle?

Comment: A third world country problem, we have a stupid english ... Sorry, but anyway, what happens is that those tags that use str_replace may arrive as <#Link> <#LINK>, <#link> ... I need a way to ignore case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output = str_ireplace(array_keys($tag),array_values($tag),$output);
```

`str_ireplace()` is the case-insensitive version of `str_replace()`.

Comment: Simple! I had not known this function, thanks!